# How do shells handle TTY?

Tags: node.js, bash, shell, unix, tty

I'm writing a dummy shell in nodejs to figure out how they work, and have realised a hole in my understanding. Specifically, in NodeJS, you can detect a shell in TTY mode using `process.<stream>.isTTY`. But if I spawn my nodejs instance using the following command

```js
import cp from 'node:child_process';

const proc = cp.spawn('node', ['-p', 'Boolean(process.stdin.isTTY)']);

process.stdin.pipe(proc.stdin);
proc.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
proc.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);

await new Promise((ok, err) => proc.once('exit', code => code == 0 ? ok() : err()));
```

Whereas using `{ stdio: 'inherit' }` does some magic which causes the filedescriptors to be passed down to the child process, and along with it, the TTY mode.

```js
import cp from 'node:child_process';

const proc = cp.spawn('node', ['-p', 'Boolean(process.stdin.isTTY)'], { stdio: 'inherit' });

await new Promise((ok, err) => proc.once('exit', code => code == 0 ? ok() : err()));
```

Here, the value `true` is printed, whereas above, either `false` or `undefined`.
This means that there is a difference between piping streams and TTY modes.

My question is specifically about how shells such as BASH or FISH handle this, and what the actual distinction is.

How do child processes inherit this TTY mode, and what happens when the user wishes to pipe one process to another. How do shells which allow you to split panes work? I'm not referring to terminal emulators such as XTerm or Konsole, but the actual shell which can display two simultaneous processes which both seem to be TTY enabled.

Comment: Which shell allows you to split panes?

Comment: Now that you ask, I can't think of the name of it, but I remember something in Rust. Possibly nushell, but I promise I saw it somewhere

Comment: I think you're just confused. On Unix, child processes inherit their parents' standard file descriptors by default. Shells create pipes between their children when needed (e.g. in `ls | cat`, the shell connects `ls`'s stdout to `cat`'s stdin using a pipe and leaves the rest untouched), but that's all. Look up terminal multiplexers, maybe that's what you saw.

Comment: Terminal Multiplexer sounds right. I'll look into it. I'd also just like to point out that the reason I'm asking is to clear up my confusion. If you're able to provide me some more details, possibly in answer form, I'll accept it.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken there is no magic. Connected to a TTY simply means that your stdout and stdin are ultimately connected to a terminal. Not connected to a TTY means that one of them is connected to something else like a file or a device. What the test does is simply call `ioctl()` with some arguments to try to figure out what stdin and stdout are connected to. For example if `ioctl()` allows you to set baud rates then you're connected to a serial device (which may or may not be a terminal) etc.

Comment: Oh. You mention streaming. That's not being connected. That's calling a javascript (or C) function (callback) to copy data from a source to an output. Being connected is literally setting the process's first and second file descriptors (fd 0 and 1) to a stdin and stdout that's connected to a terminal.

Comment: Well, as they say, _magic is just science we don't understand yet_, so I think magic is the perfect word for it :P but thank you, that actually does clear things up a bit.

Comment: From my description above it should be obvious that shells implement piping using file descriptor manipulation, not streaming.

Comment: So to summarise, the filedescriptors themselves (the actual OS construct represented by the number) is inherited by the child process, and instead of copying data between shell stdio and subprocess stdio, the child reads directly from the parent's stdio. Is that somewhat correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. There isn't much to put in an answer so I won't post one. Good day

Comment: Ah no problem. Well if you wanted to anyway. But thank you all very much#

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll leave the split panes for the moment. Also, don't think about inheriting TTY-modes; in the context of shells that concept doesnot really have any value.

I'll be doing bash, because I don't know fish.

You can test if a shell is interactive with

```
[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'not-interactive'
```

If you pipe to a shell, the shell becomes non-interactive:

```
$ cat | bash
[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'not-interactive'
not-interactive
```

On the other hand, `[ -t 0 ]` tests whether your shell reads from a tty. Consider the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
[[ $- == *i* ]] && echo 'Interactive' || echo 'not-interactive'
[ -t 0 ] && echo 'connected to tty' || echo 'not connected to tty'
```

You can run this in different ways. In the current shell:

```
$ . test.sh 
Interactive
connected to tty
```

As a script:

```
$ bash test.sh
not-interactive
connected to tty
```

or on a pipe:

```
$ echo | bash test.sh
not-interactive
not connected to tty
```

or force interactive with `-i`:

```
$ echo | bash -i test.sh
Interactive
not connected to tty
```

So, what determines if a shell is interactive? According to the source-code:

```
     A shell is interactive if the `-i' flag was given, or if all of
     the following conditions are met:
        no -c command
        no arguments remaining or the -s flag given
        standard input is a terminal
        standard error is a terminal
```

During the start-up, bash tests this:

```
  if (forced_interactive ||             /* -i flag */
      (!command_execution_string &&     /* No -c command and ... */
       wordexp_only == 0 &&             /* No --wordexp and ... */
       ((arg_index == argc) ||          /*   no remaining args or... */
        read_from_stdin) &&             /*   -s flag with args, and */
       isatty (fileno (stdin)) &&       /* Input is a terminal and */
       isatty (fileno (stderr))))       /* error output is a terminal. */
    init_interactive ();
  else
    init_noninteractive ();
```

So, bash determines it at the start-up of the shell.

The point is, that the TTY is not really handled differently. Sure, you can test if the shell is interactive; you can test if the shell reads from a TTY, but that's it. The TTY is just a file descriptor for the shell. In the source code, you can see that there are tests whether STDIN is a TTY, but for the rest: the shell uses STDIN, not a TTY as input. The assumption that TTYs are treated differently is wrong.

Comment: Thank you these are fantastic, but I was hoping for a more technical explanation of how this actually works, as I am already familiar-ish with bash.

Comment: Something like in the additions?

Comment: Unfortunately, I was referring to how TTY devices are handled within the shell, rather than  how to detect them, but this is certainly helpful to me as I'm always in the search of snippets and things.

Comment: The point is, that the TTY is not really handled differently. Sure, you can test if the shell is interactive; you can test if the shell reads from a TTY, but that's it.  The TTY is just a file descriptor for the shell. In the sourcecode, you can see that there are tests whether STDIN is a TTY, but for the rest: the shell uses STDIN, not a TTY as input. Your assumption that TTYs are treated differently is wrong.

Comment: Would you mind putting that in your answer, as that actually clears up most of my confusion. I'll click accept